# how to get video from dkimagepicker ios using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I can write image and fetch an image using following code succesfully,

```
public func writeImageToFile(path: String, completeBlock: (success: Bool) -> Void)
```

but I can't write and fetch video to play using:

```
  func showImagePickerWithAssetType(assetType: DKImagePickerControllerAssetType,
                                  allowMultipleType: Bool,
                                  sourceType: DKImagePickerControllerSourceType = .Both,
                                  allowsLandscape: Bool,
                                  singleSelect: Bool) {

    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    pickerController.assetType = assetType
    pickerController.allowsLandscape = allowsLandscape
    pickerController.allowMultipleTypes = allowMultipleType
    pickerController.sourceType = sourceType
    pickerController.singleSelect = singleSelect
    pickerController.defaultSelectedAssets = self.assets
    pickerController.didSelectAssets = {

        [unowned self] (assets: [DKAsset]) in

        self.assets = assets


        for asst in self.assets! {
```

///  [ START :  CREATE A DIRECTORY IN DEVICE FOR STORING MEDIA   ]  >>>>>>>>

```
            var dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
            dirPath = dirPath + "/Media/"
            do{
                try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtPath(dirPath, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
            }
            catch{
            }
```

///  [ END :   CREATE A DIRECTORY IN DEVICE FOR STORING MEDIA   ]  >>>>>>>>

```
            var fileName = "filename.mov"               
            dirPath=dirPath.stringByAppendingString(fileName)

                fileName = self.Utils.randomVideoName(10) as String
                fileType = "video"
                dirPath=dirPath.stringByAppendingString(fileName)

               asst.writeAVToFile(dirPath, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality, completeBlock: { (success) in
```

//   PLAY VIDEO FROM SAVED FILE PATH

```
                let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(string: dirPath)!)      
               // let avPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path)!)            
                let avPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: avPlayerItem)
                let player = AVPlayerViewController()
                player.player = avPlayer                    
                avPlayer.play()                    
                self.presentViewController(player, animated: true, completion: nil)

                })

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using https://github.com/zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController

Comment: What error are you getting in particular?

Comment: from DKImage picker i got file as DKAsset form, in the case of image following code works                                                 asst.writeImageToFile(dirPath, completeBlock: { (success) in                          })                                                                                                           using this i can save image in .jpg format in my document directory. Similarly i can save video in .mov/mp4 format. But when i try to retrieving that file and play in my app it show as corrupted form. I can't play

Answer (score 0):

```
    let pickerController = DKImagePickerController()
    
    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor : UIColor.white
    ]
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.systemIndigo
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
    
    pickerController.delegate = self
    pickerController.allowSwipeToSelect = true
    pickerController.showsCancelButton = true
    pickerController.assetType = .allVideos
    pickerController.didSelectAssets = { (assets: [DKAsset]) in

        for asset in assets {
            if asset.type == .video {
                asset.fetchAVAsset { AVAsset, info in
                    
                    if let videoUrl = AVAsset as? AVURLAsset {
                        print("vd: \(videoUrl)")
                        print("url: \(videoUrl.url)")
                        let videoData = try Data(contentsOf: videoUrl.url)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
    }
    
    self.present(pickerController, animated: true)
```